# In what scene does the character Bauernfänger (played by Theo Lingen) appear in Fritz Lang's M (1931)?

Tags: casting, m

I'm trying to figure out who "Bauernfänger" is in Lang's [*M*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0022100/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), what scene(s) he is in. He is supposedly played by the actor Theo Lingen. I haven't spotted him yet in viewing the film, and I can't find a reference to that name in the subtitles. "M" of course is Lang's trolling of the Nazi party.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: [con-man](http://www.oocities.org/emruf/M.html), but you'll probably have better luck on Movies SE as already suggested.

Answer (score 2):

As Lars Bosteen suggests in his comment, Theo Lingen plays the character referred to as the "con-man" in [this transcript](http://www.oocities.org/emruf/M.html). (That's what ["bauernfänger" translates to](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Bauernf%C3%A4nger.html).)

He first appears in the film around 29 minutes in, lying on the sofa and smoking a cigarette and then doing card tricks at the table:

Comment: Yeah, that's him - the voice is unmistakable :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a trailer for the movie [here](http://www.movie4k.at/m---eine-stadt-sucht-einen-mrder.html) and the cast is introduced starting at 1:35.

The character played by Theo Lingen is shown from 1:50  to 1:55. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Unfortunately, I could not find a script so far. Thus, I can not really describe  the scenes he is playing in. But maybe you recognise him now, when re-watching the film.